# Get the key from the most frequent value in an array, or the highest key if there is a value "tie"

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like the following:

2021-04-05 19:45:04 : "0001"
2021-04-05 18:45:03 : "1220"
2021-04-05 17:45:03 : "0001"
2021-04-05 16:45:03 : "1220"
2021-04-05 15:45:03 : "0001"
2021-04-05 14:45:03 : "1220"
2021-04-05 13:45:03 : "3321"

In the above scenario, among the seven elements, we have 3 unique values. 0001 exists 3 times, 1220 exists 3 times, and 3321 exists once. I need to get the most frequent value in the array, and if there is a tie, I need to get the most RECENT, most frequent value.

Currently my code returns 3321 because the date is the most recent. I would need to look at both 0001 and 1220 since they appear the most, and then ultimately I would need to select 1220 since it's the value that appears the most with the most recent date time / key.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: Use `array_count_values()` to get the counts of each unique value. Get the value with the highest count from that, then get all the corresponding keys. Sort the keys and return the highest one.

Comment: What happens when array_count_values() returns an array where keys have multiple of the same counts? 

i.e.
3321 = {int} 1  
0001 = {int} 3  
1220 = {int} 3

Comment: Put all of them in the array of keys and values, sort the keys, and return the highest one.

Comment: @Tel is it possible to have a tie after implementing the two sorting rules?  Do you want to return a single string value, or possibly an array of most-occurring&latest values?  Please clarify the input using `var_export()`.

Comment: Your question is missing its failed coding attempt and/or proof of research. @Tel

Answer (score 1):

There are fringe cases to be aware of -- for instance, what should happen if there is a tie for the most occurrences AND the most recent timestamp?

In the absence of that specification in the question, create a temporary array which contains the running tally for each id and its latest datetime stamp.

Then call `arsort()` on the smaller/grouped array to order by `count` DESC, then `stamp` DESC.

Finally echo the first key in the grouped array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N2phs))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $datetime => $id) {
    if (!isset($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id] = ['count' => 1, 'stamp' => $datetime];
    } else {
        if ($datetime > $result[$id]['stamp']) {
            $result[$id]['stamp'] = $datetime;
        }
        ++$result[$id]['count'];
    }
}

arsort($result);
echo key($result);
// 0001
```

Answer (score 0):

On the face of it, this looks straightforward, but the soution involves some fiddly counting and filtering:

```
$arr = [
    "2021-04-05 19:45:04"=> "0001",
"2021-04-05 18:45:03" => "1220",
"2021-04-05 17:45:03" => "0001",
"2021-04-05 16:45:03" => "1220",
"2021-04-05 15:45:03" => "0001",
"2021-04-05 14:45:03" => "1220",
"2021-04-05 13:45:03" => "3321",
];

$freqs = array_count_values($arr);
// Gives ['0001'=>3, '1220'=>3, '3321'=>1]

$maxFreq = max($freqs);
// max frequency = 3

// Get just the count elements that match the max count
$filteredFreqs = array_filter($freqs, function($a) use ($maxFreq){return $a === $maxFreq;});
// Gives ['0001'=>3, '1220'=>3]


// Filter down to the original elements with values that match the max freqs
// For this data remove any entries where value is not 1220 or 0001
$newArray = array_filter($arr, function($v) use ($filteredFreqs){return in_array($v, array_keys($filteredFreqs));
} );

// Finally, get the keys and find the latest
$latest = max(array_keys($newArray));
// then get the value
$result = $newArray[$latest]; // 0001
```